# Ginger vs Ginger Root

Tags: ginger

Does anyone know if ginger root is the same as ginger?
I have a recipe with dried ginger but can only find dried ginger root.
Hopefully someone knows the answer

Answer (score 27):

Ginger is a root. Ginger root is ginger.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger

"**Ginger** or **ginger root** is the rhizome of the plant Zingiber officinale, consumed as a delicacy, medicine, or spice."

If you write ginger too many times it doesn't look like a word anymore.

Comment: haha.. thanks! 
I assumed they were the same thing, but wasn't was certain :)

Comment: *However*, fresh ginger root is quite different from the dried powdered form, and I wouldn't advise directly substituting the two.

Comment: @logophobe definitely yes, dried vs. fresh spices/herbs have different strengths in flavour. However, OP mentions both are dried, so I didn't bother to mention it.

Comment: Re: the last sentence, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-the-feeling-you-get-after-looking-at-a-word-for-to

Comment: @MarchHo haha thanks, I quite like the sound of 'spelling dazzle'!

Answer (score 5):

Ginger root is the root itself. Ginger is the spice derived from said root. Ginger, the spice, is just dried ginger root ground into a powder.

This, of course, is all just semantics. You'd not be wrong to call ginger root just "ginger".

Comment: I think this is a good answer, and probably gets at the OP's concern: if a recipe calls for `ginger root` it needs the whole root, while `ginger` might be calling for the powdered form (though it also may not be).  Though the original question said `dried ginger root` which is a bit odd (could mean the whole root dried I guess?)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ginger Root (fresh) and Ginger (dried/ground) are the same product, but different form and intensity.

Fresh Ginger Root is plucked from the dirt in the ground and is found in the Produce section of the grocery store. It is a knobby looking thing.

[image: Ginger root]

Ginger is the dried/ground form of fresh ginger root, just called ginger or ground ginger, and can be found bottled in the spice aisle of the grocery store. (I buy it online cheaper at Thrive Market and it comes in plastic bags, which I transfer to my ginger spice bottle.)

The ratio for substituting ground ginger for grated ginger root (according to Food.com) is 1/8 teaspoon ground ginger for 1 Tablespoon grated ginger root*.

*Please note that FRESH ginger root can have different intensities usually based on just how fresh it is. (And it doesn't have a long shelf life, so you can learn to freeze it.) A fresher ginger root has a shiny coat and will be a lot juicier and more potent than a not-so-fresh ginger root that has a duller coat and is a lot drier.

Answer (score 0):

Ginger is a root. So ginger root is the same.

Comment: This is the same thing the other answer already said. It doesn't seem to add any value here.